# how to prevent shadowing $parent scope inside a directive using ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm working on a directive to handle table settings and in particular the pageSize.

```
<table-settings page-size="pagination.pageSize" sizes="PAGE_SIZES" </table-settings>
```

I'm facing the problem of scope shadowing since `pageSize` param is a primitive wich is binded to a `ng-model` inside another directive(a dropdown menu).

I know I can use an  object instead like `pageSize = {value:5}` but it's not handy/natural to use.

I not a big fan of using $parent `ng-model='$parent.pageSize'` since I'm not sure which $parent it refer to.

So I decided to add a pointer to the directive'scope, that I can use to "scope" my binding
inside the template. (like using controller/controllerAs syntax)

basically it look like this

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, controller) {
  scope.tableSettings = scope;
}
```

and it's used like this:

`<input type="text" ng-model="tableSettings.pageSize">`

So I wondering if it's a good or bad idea ?
And if it's a bad idea, if you have a better one ?

thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right.Why did not you use a two way binding variable?

Comment: because I could use pagination on other place (ex in ng-repeat pagination).  @binding implies another '&' type binding to call a handler on pagesize update (ex: do a request with a new pageSize)

Answer (score 0):

If your directive is assumed to always require a specific parent Directive with Controller you can use the `require` option in your directive settings to require that controller to be a parent (not necessarily a direct parent).

As a bonus you get that controller injected to your `link` function and you can take your parameters from there.

Read more about it in the docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive - look for 'Creating Directives that Communicate' at the bottom)

Comment: I know that but the directive won't require another directive's controller (it's widget to show a table settings, like show hide columns and page size setting).